# Why is C not OOP if it has structs

Tags: c++, c, oop, struct

Having done some C++ I have noticed that C also has structs - surely C should be considered OOP if it has them?

Comment: The meaning of OOP is highly subjective; it's not even clear that saying "language X is (not) OOP" actually makes any sense.

Comment: OOP is a paradigm and can be emulated in any language. What is different is how much a certain language supports a paradigm.

Comment: I don't see how this is `Not Constructive`. This can definitely be answered with specific facts & references. This could be a duplicate but then it should be marked so.It could be too broad to answer but then it should be migrated to programmers SE.Voting to Re-Open.

Comment: @Als: apologies to you and others, for my earlier vote for closing.  I just voted to reopen...  I realize I was too quick in closing, as indeed the question can draws specfic factual responses.  Never the less the question is weak, IMO, being rather broad and the OP having apparently taken little time to research the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it does not have some of the basic OOPs features of:
Inheritance
Polymorphism  and so on

Comment: That's not really true; although the language doesn't explicitly support it, with a few small tricks, inheritance and polymorphism are achievable.

Comment: @Dave:There is a difference between achieving certain functionalities by hackery and functionalities which the language explicitly supports and was designed for.Just because You can do a certain thing in a programming language doesn't mean the language was meant to do/support that.The argument doesn't really hold good.

Comment: I would agree with you if it wasn't so present in c code. Glib and Xlib are very object-oriented. It's more fair to say that there is implicit OO support, but not explicit.

Comment: @Dave:How can you say there is implicit support when C was never desgined for OOPs features and neither as an OOPs Language in the first place? Just because You can shoot yourself in the foot,doesn't mean You were supposed & meant to do that.That is an unfair & at the best wrong assumption.

Comment: C was not conceived for natively supporting objects (meaning supporting not only the structuring of data structures, as structs do, but also supporting natively inheritance, member functions/methods, polymorphism, etc). Another thing is that one could code hundreds of lines of wrappers to simulate that functionality (welcome to C++). If you @Dave want to work with such an extreme definition of OOP, one could argue, owing to the same logic, that any Turing-complete programming language is (potentially) OOP, which would immediately throw the use/value of the concept of OOP itself out the window,

Answer (score 4):

From Wikipedia:

> Object-oriented programming (OOP) is a programming paradigm using "objects" – data structures consisting of data fields and methods together with their interactions.

In C, data and methods (functions) are separated from each other. There aren't any "objects" in C like described above.

In e.g. C++ and Objective-C they aren't separated.

Answer (score 2):

Because structs only allow for structured programming. For real OO programming, you need for the language to at least support encapsulation, inheritance and member functions.

Comment: C supports encapsulation. Go has no inheritance nor member functions. Isn't Go OOP?

Comment: Arguably, C does not support encapsulation, because it does not restrict access to "object" components (see the Wikipedia article on encapsulation). What C does support is data abstraction.

Comment: C also has inheritance and polymorphism if you use pointers and put the "super" as the first member of a struct. Encapsulation can be achieved using opaque structs.

Comment: @WTP: You can use hackery to simulate Inheritance and Polymorphism in C, but C as a language neither supports nor endorses those principles.It was not designed to support them,it is just that they can be simulated with some hacks.